# Form - label and input vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to vertically align the label with the input on the right. I've read other questions on here but nothing seems to be fine for my example. This is my attempt, but label text is aligned to top.

.css:

```
label{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    min-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    clear: both;
    text-align:right;
    display: table-cell;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
     box-sizing: border-box;    
     padding-right: 10px;
}

input[type="text"]{
    width:50%;
}

.pers_form{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display: table;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="pers_form">
    <label for "example">Example</label>
    <input type="text" id="example" name="example" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking `display: table;` on `<input>` and have unwanted `float: left;` on `<label>`. Fixed code (and remember, there are plenty other ways to achieve vertical alignment):

```
label {
  width:50%;
  min-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  clear: both;
  text-align:right;
  display: table-cell;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width:50%;
  display: table-cell;
} 
.pers_form {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display: table;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qop7d4av/

Comment: Hello, it's almost working! Just one thing: if I remove float:left, then width 50% on input type means 25% (50% of the remaining part). Also, I used to know that float:left is necessary to aling more elements on the same line. Could you explain why I can remove it in this example?
Also, label min-height is not working.

Comment: There are many way to do vertical aligns, using `float` property is just one of them. See this article: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ .

Comment: @bardzsusny I've read it, thanks. Though, I still don't understand why if I've a select type on the right, label is not 34px.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
.pers_form{
    width:400px;
}

label{
    width:200px;
}

input{
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This should position the label on the left and in input on the right inline